# jquery animate a hover

Tags: jquery

I followed the example here

http://www.incg.nl/blog/2008/hover-block-jquery/

And that worked. What I did too was make it bigger and added a background image. Adjusted the CSS to move the hover animation to a specific spot in the background image. That all works too but animates when you hover anywhere over the background image. I would like it to only hover when you hover over the animation image or can i set like margins?

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.hover_block li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            top: '374px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    });
    $('ul.hover_block2 li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            left: '178px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #666
}

ul.hover_block {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

ul.hover_block li, ul.hover_block2 li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 315px;
    padding-top: 78px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-image: url('images/2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.hover_block li a, ul.hover_block2 li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font: 1.6em/1.3 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul.hover_block li a, ul.hover_block2 li a {
    text-decoration: none
}

ul.hover_block li img, ul.hover_block2 li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul class="hover_block">
        <li>
            <a href=""><img src="images/3.png" alt="" /> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use an image map (not recommended by me), or create a smaller element to attach the hover function to.

Answer (score 0):

i think the selector your using "ul.hover_block li" refers to hovering over the list element, which is not the image. 
if you change the selector to something that refers to the img rather than the li it should work,

Have a look at this: jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/eYp99/